# mysql select issue

Tags: mysql

I have a table called items.   IN this table there are many columns.  One of the columns is called 'source'.    What I would like to do is select records from the table. I would like to select the latest 5 records with the condition that the 'source' columns are all distinct.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SOURCE from items order by time DESC LIMIT 5
```

but I need the whole record not just the source, when I try to include more columns it doesn't work .

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM items  WHERE item_section='sp_500'   GROUP BY source  ORDER BY time DESC    LIMIT 3
```

but it doesn't give me the LATEST records

Comment: i am surprised by the fact that this is so difficult, i must be missing something

Comment: could you post one example of the table you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky.

Try this.

```
SELECT items.* 
  FROM items
  INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT source, max(time) maxtime
       FROM bbc
       GROUP BY source
       ORDER BY max(time) DESC
       LIMIT 5
    ) s
ON items.source = s.source and items.time = maxtime
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE source IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT source FROM items ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5
)
```

Comment: this will return more than one column for same source name, so result may be >5

Comment: got one of these Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/market2d/public_html/common/linkwriter_front.php on line 12

though what you wrote looks good

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM items as itm,(SELECT pk,DISTINCT source as src FROM items ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5) as temp  WHERE itm.pk = temp.pk
```

where `pk` is your primary key

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee the selection of the latest five records,  I would advise you to add a new column called `"created"` and insert into it the `time()` of the creation of the record.

Example:

```
Insert into items values(ID,SOURCE, CREATED )
```

When selecting the latest five record you could do :

```
SELECT source, Max(created) FROM items GROUP By created LIMIT 5
```